# Patagames PDFium scrolling with Keyboard

Tags: pdfium

I'm a bit in need for some help. I'm trying to scroll a PDF in Patagames PDFium .net control using the keyboard. Unfortunately I can't get it to scroll correctly and am looking for some sample code (VB or C#) to scroll 'line wize (lets say 10 pixels per keypress)' and 'page wize'. Can anybody help me out here? TIA a lot. Ole

Answer (score 0):

### Never mind. Found an answer.

```
   Private Sub PdfViewer1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles PdfViewer1.KeyDown

      Dim pageStep As Integer = PdfViewer1.AutoScrollMinSize.Height / PdfViewer1.Document.Pages.Count
      Dim lineStep As Integer = pageStep / 30
      Dim asp As Point = PdfViewer1.AutoScrollPosition


      Select Case e.KeyCode
         Case Keys.Up
            PdfViewer1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(asp.X, -asp.Y - lineStep)
         Case Keys.Down
            PdfViewer1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(asp.X, -asp.Y + lineStep)
         Case Keys.PageUp
            PdfViewer1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(asp.X, -asp.Y - pageStep)
         Case Keys.PageDown
            PdfViewer1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(asp.X, -asp.Y + pageStep)
      End Select

   End Sub
```